# Recursive procedure that repeatedly applies any procedure a number of times

Tags: scheme

```
(define (repeated proc n)
  (if (= n 0)
      (lambda (x) x)
      (lambda (x)
        (proc 
         ((repeated proc (- n 1)) x)))))
```

I am having some trouble understanding how this procedure returns a procedure that takes a single argument and recursively applies proc to it n times.

If n = 2, is this the procedure that is returned ?

```
(lambda (x) (proc (((lambda (x) (proc (((lambda (x) x)) x)))) x)))
```

How do we evaluate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what's happening

```
   (repeated proc 2)
-> (lambda (x) (proc ((repeated proc 1)                         x)))
-> (lambda (x) (proc ((lambda (x) (proc ((repeated proc 0) x))) x)))
-> (lambda (x) (proc ((lambda (x) (proc ((lambda (x) x)    x))) x)))
```

not

```
   (lambda (x) (proc (((lambda (x) (proc (((lambda (x) x)) x)))) x)))
```

Testing

```
(define (R2 proc) (lambda (x) (proc ((lambda (x) (proc ((lambda (x) x) x))) x))))
((R2 add1) 5)
=> 7
```